# Label faces in Picasa per album

Tags: picasa-web-albums

There used to be a link/feature in Picasa Web Album to just label faces in photos per album online.  In each album it would list the faces it could find with facial recognition software trying to match similar faces to actual contacts.

Now this link is gone.  Has it been permanently removed?  It used to be on the right column in the middle.  All that is there is now 'People in this album' with a 'View All' link that links to a page that doesn't do the above-- instead it lists all faces in *all* albums.

How can I label faces in Picasa on a per album basis online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't, at the moment. Use Picasa on your local computer.**

I loved this online feature too, and it's sad that it's gone. However, seeing that the capability appeared only online, and later in the application, I suspect that they removed it from online because it's difficult to merge your face/name assignments from online into your local Picasa installation. It's a lot easier, and more natural, to do the tagging before uploading.

Comment: I think you might be right.  I rather they had it available in both (web & client).

Comment: WTF Google?? I was uploading all the photos there and deleting the original ones, because there is no need to have two copies.. and now they removed that option?